# Use built-in Laptop Camera in ROS

Tags: libuvc-camera, usb-camera, ubuntu, camera, ubuntu-trusty

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I get video stream from a built-in Laptop Camera in ROS Indigo, Ubuntu 14.04 ? I found a ROS packages for USB webcam i.e.libuvc_camera, but can the same packages be used for built-in camera as well?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259784/use-built-in-laptop-camera-in-ros/) by [vacky11](https://answers.ros.org/users/29229/vacky11/) on ROS Answers with karma: 272 on 2017-04-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed usb_cam package and it works fine for my built-in laptop camera.

---

Originally posted by [vacky11](https://answers.ros.org/users/29229/vacky11/) with karma: 272 on 2017-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2